# Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I have a project which uses a `WelcomeActivity` which extends `FragmentActivity`. I use the support library, so `android-support-v4.jar` is in the `libs` folder. When I run this app, there are no problems.

However, I want to add ActionBarSherlock to the project. In the ABS project I use `actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar` and `android-support-v4-r6-googlemaps.jar` in the `libs` folder. In my app project I add the ABS library, and when I try to run the app, this error occurs:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
```

To solve this, I removed the `android-support-v4.jar` from my app's `libs` folder. When I now start my app, the app crashes with this logcat:

```
08-01 18:59:11.182: W/dalvikvm(13338): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity; (620)
08-01 18:59:11.182: W/dalvikvm(13338): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;' failed
08-01 18:59:11.182: W/dalvikvm(13338): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/myapp/welcome/WelcomeActivity; (109)
08-01 18:59:11.182: W/dalvikvm(13338): Link of class 'Lcom/myapp/welcome/WelcomeActivity;' failed
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/dalvikvm(13338): Could not find class 'com.myapp.welcome.WelcomeActivity', referenced from method com.myapp.MainDispatcherActivity.startWelcomeActivity
08-01 18:59:11.182: W/dalvikvm(13338): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 690 (Lcom/myapp/welcome/WelcomeActivity;) in Lcom/myapp/MainDispatcherActivity;
08-01 18:59:11.182: D/dalvikvm(13338): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0002
08-01 18:59:11.182: D/dalvikvm(13338): VFY: dead code 0x0004-000b in Lcom/myapp/MainDispatcherActivity;.startWelcomeActivity ()V
08-01 18:59:11.182: D/AndroidRuntime(13338): Shutting down VM
08-01 18:59:11.182: W/dalvikvm(13338): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.welcome.WelcomeActivity
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at com.myapp.MainDispatcherActivity.startWelcomeActivity(MainDispatcherActivity.java:33)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at com.myapp.MainDispatcherActivity.startProperActivity(MainDispatcherActivity.java:26)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at com.myapp.MainDispatcherActivity.onCreate(MainDispatcherActivity.java:19)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
08-01 18:59:11.182: E/AndroidRuntime(13338):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit**
I have another project which uses the same ABS library, and runs fine. I have no idea what I've done differently, or which settings are wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems this error occurred because I didn't have this line in the AndroidManifest.xml file, in the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663686/link-of-class-landroid-support-v4-app-watson-failed-unable-to-resolve-superc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I think it is the same problem at the Build Path-> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export, the "android-support-v4.jar" needs to be checked.

Hope it is useful to you.

Comment: This comment was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks man! This is it. The support Jar was included in the list, but NOT checked.

Comment: thanks very much, it does work. But generally the android-support-v4.jar was added into 'android private library'. Why sometimes against this rule?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the compiler compliance for the actionbarsherlock library project? Right click on the library project, go to properties. Under java compiler, make sure compliance is set to 1.6. I had a similar issue, and found the compliance set to 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run into it myself, but I think the [doc](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) for `ActionBarSherlock` says you need to extend `SherlockFragmentActivity` rather than `FragmentActivity`.  It may not be *the* problem, but it's *a* problem.

Comment: The `WelcomeActivity` doesn't need an ActionBar, so `FragmentActivity` is enough. I have, however, tried it with `SherlockFragmentActivity`, which didn't work.

Comment: Sorry to not be more helpful!  Perhaps this ABS tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY) will be useful to you?  I did find a post on the ABS google group with someone experiencing a similar issue re: the standard support lib vs the googlemaps one:  (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/actionbarsherlock/library/actionbarsherlock/UlmlYAyUruY/rFGrA86gVx0J) but it's un-answered.  I'm afraid that's about all I've got.