# Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/Watson; failed - Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockActivity

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-logcat

I have an android project that I was working on a few weeks ago it was working fine in my last attempt, but now the project all compiles fine, but while launching application, I am getting the following warning and it crashes my application.

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/Watson;
Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/Watson;' failed

Unable to resolve superclass of 
Lcom/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity;
```

Please tell me how can i fix this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I noticed that I had this problem after updating ADT Plugin Revision 22. This problem raised due to new Android Package named as Android Private Libraries is not included on my old projects.

I fix this issue by following the below steps:

1.Right Click on project

2.Build Path-> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export

3.Check the Android Private Libraries and click OK

4.Clean the project

5.Rebuild the project

Comment: Great!! Yesterday i suffered the same problem, you solved that.

Comment: Awesome was struggling for hrs !

Comment: Fantastic! I found that I had to do the same on every library project I was importing.